# SSL for auto generated sub domain

Tags: ssl, wildcard-subdomain

I have to use SSL for my subdomain as well for main domain. My requirements are to crete sub domain on the go, 
for ex
sub1.mydomain.com
sub2.mydomain.com
etc

There is wildcard domain, please explain and also provide the link to buy it ans set up it.

BR
Gopal

Answer (score 0):

Almost all CA offer wildcard certificates. If you purchase a certificate for *.domain.com, it will basically cover your main domain and any first level sub-domains.
I got one from [here](https://www.globalsign.com/ssl/)
Setting it up depends on the type of server you are using. There is a simple guide [here](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1309527-install-an-ssl-certificate---overview)